# Setting camera ISO and Exposure parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am a brand new coder and new to Stack Overflow. I am looking to set my camera settings in my iOS app at a certain pre-set ISO and Exposure. How would I go about doing this?  This works for a sliding motion, but I wish to have both at a pre-set programmatically defined value.

```
func updateDeviceSettings(focusValue : Float, isoValue : Float) {
if let device = captureDevice {
    if(device.lockForConfiguration(nil)) {
        device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focusValue, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
            //
        })


        let minISO = device.activeFormat.minISO
        let maxISO = device.activeFormat.maxISO
        let clampedISO = isoValue * (maxISO - minISO) + minISO

        device.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(AVCaptureExposureDurationCurrent, ISO: clampedISO, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
            //
        })

        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this question still unanswered? Can you please describe your goal more accurate?